# What role does the "id" in variable(str name, int id) play?

Tags: rascal

I am using the Rascal library for accessing syntax trees that are produced by the Eclipse Java compiler (JDT.rsc).

I am trying to get a fix on how the abstract syntax tree works. One thing that eludes me is the "variableBinding". Imagine a very simple class `MyClass` with one method `doNothing()` containing one statement, a variable declaration `myVar`. The declaration of the string variable `myVar` is represented in the AST-snipped below.

Inside the `@bindings` annotation, under the `variableBinding` key, there is a list that represents the consecutive components of a path to the variable `myVar`. The last item represents the actual variable itself, which is represented by the Id constructor `variable(str name, int id)`.

**Question:** What is the meaning of the id?

It certainly isn't unique, because when I duplicate the method `doNothing()` and name it `doNothing2()`, I find `variable("doNothing",0)` and `variable("doNothing2",0)` in the AST. What exactly does it *identify*?

```
...
variableDeclarationFragment(
  "myVar",
  none())[
  @bindings=(
    "typeBinding":entity([
        package("java"),
        package("lang"),
        class("String")
      ]),
    "variableBinding":entity([
        class("MyClass"),
        method(
          "doNothing",
          [],
          entity([primitive(void())])),
        variable("myVar",0) // Here it's 0, but 
      ])
  ),
  @javaType=entity([
      package("java"),
      package("lang"),
      class("String")
    ]),
  @location=|project://my-project/src/MyClass.java|(60,5,<4,15>,<4,19>)
]
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This id field actually appears to be an identifier assigned internally by Eclipse. You can see the JavaDoc for the IVariableBinding interface here, which is the source of the id:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/IVariableBinding.html#getVariableId()

Just click on the link for `getVariableId()` if it doesn't take you there, and instead just takes you to the page for the interface. This is the method called to get the id. From what I can tell, it isn't very useful and can probably safely be ignored in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do think however that it can serve a certain purpose, because local variables declared in different blocks (if, for, while) have almost the same `variableBinding`, and the only way to distinguish between these is through the `id`. I was assuming the `id` was supposed to be a global identifier, but the only thing that globally identifies the variable node is the complete `variableBinding` entity (with package, class, method, variable (including `id`) etc).

Comment: I misread the code! So Mark is right indeed. Thanks. Let's also have a look at the new interface that is coming out for JDT to check what is going on there.

Comment: That is a good point -- the number itself isn't really meaningful, but it does provide a way to ensure that different variable instances can be distinguished.